# GWT application bandwidth congestion issue

Tags: gwt

I am curious to know this question for a long time about GWT Application. Why Bandwidth consumption is high during first run on the server and after that bandwidth consumption decreases big time? So why this happen? Please Reply as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the whole application (loads of JS/image/CSS) is loaded at start up. Additional calls to fetch data are made via AJAX. Search the interwebs for *GWT bootstrapping* to learn more. You can improve said bootstrapping using code splitting and client bundles. See the GWT documentation http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html